# Assigning empty list

Tags: python, list, binding

I don't really know how I stumbled upon this, and I don't know what to think about it, but apparently `[] = []` is a legal operation in python, so is `[] = ''`, but `'' = []` is not allowed. It doesn't seem to have any effect though, but I'm wondering: what the hell ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to Python's multiple assignment (sequence unpacking):

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
```

works the same as:

```
[a, b, c] = 1, 2, 3
```

Since strings are sequences of characters, you can also do:

```
a, b, c = "abc"    # assign each character to a variable
```

What you've discovered is the degenerative case: empty sequences on both sides. Syntactically valid because it's a list on the left rather than a tuple. Nice find; never thought to try that before!

Interestingly, if you try that with an empty tuple on the left, Python complains:

```
() = ()            # SyntaxError: can't assign to ()
```

Looks like the Python developers forgot to close a little loophole!

Answer (score 1):

Do some search on packing/unpacking on python and you will find your answer.
This is basically for assigning multiple variables in a single go.

```
>>> [a,v] = [2,4]
>>> print a
2
>>> print v
4
```

Comment: Makes sense, but it doesn't work with `()=()`, even though `(a,b) = (1,2)` does work !